Mini cart is not showing the added products on magento 2.4.7
When I click on the mini cart icon in the header, it should display the drop-down dialog with the added products in that block.
However, after upgrading to Magento 2.4.7, it no longer shows any products. Upon inspecting and checking the console log, I found the following:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).dropdownDialog is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (cart:3214:66)
    at HTMLDivElement.handle (jquery.js:5725:45)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5145:49)
    at elemData.handle (jquery.js:4949:47)

How can I resolve this issue?
